# Which machine learning approach can be used to predict a univariate value?

Tags: prediction

I have a stream of data coming in like below (random numbers 0-9)

> 7, 7, 0, 0, 8, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 2, 8, 5, 7, 0, 8, 7, 8, 5, 3, 2, 6, 1, 9, 5, 7, 5, 3, 4, 9, 1, 3, 5, 5, 0, 7, 7, 5, 2, 8, 8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5, 7, 1, 4, 2, 7, 8, 8, 5, 2, 7, 5, 7, 1, 7, 2, 0, 5, 7, 5, 2, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 1, 9, 1, 9, 7, 2, 3, 9, 8, 8, 4, 9, 8, 2, 5, 3, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 7, 2, 3, 8, 7, 5, 7, 3, 6, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 3, 1, 3, 0, 6, 9, 8, 0, 1, 4, 4, 9, 9, 3, 7, 4, 1, 0, 5, 0, 6, 8, 8, 8, 1, 7, 6

Ask: is to Predict the next numbers(at least 3-10).

Which approach would be helpful in getting through this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is **not** purely random (otherwise it will be difficult to make useful predictions), you can try the following:

- [Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_model): Treating your discrete numbers as states, you can use HMMs to predict the next state (next number) by looking at the last or the $n$ last states.
- Recurrent Neural Networks: Assuming you have a lot of number sequences, you can treat your numbers as time series. Train a model and predict the next number(s). [Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/) is a nice tutorial which uses LSTM cells.
- [Autoregressive models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model): AR models are quite powerful as well and have already been successfully used in finance and signal processing before the rise of deep learning.

Further this post ([Problem in discrete valued time series forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/24521/264183)) on Cross Validated might answer your question as well.